# How to deal with diarrhea when using a cathole in the wilderness?

Tags: wild-camping, hygiene, leave-no-trace, human-waste

I was sitting and thinking last night...

If you have gas and loose stool (diarrhea) and you are squatting over a [cathole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathole) in the wilderness how do keep your pants and foot wear clean?

Related

[What's the problem with burying toilet paper?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11201/whats-the-problem-with-burying-toilet-paper)

[Why are people so worried about Giardia?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/why-are-people-so-worried-about-giardia)

Comment: disrobing? seems that using a cathole isn't much different than using a [squatty potty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squat_toilet), and while it's completely possible for someone accustomed to using those to relieve oneself cleanly, i often found it was just much simpler to take everything off and then go.

Answer (score 6):

BTDT I think, but I don't remember ever having a 'problem'. As a guy who camps and also gets to use squatty potties once in a while, here's my advice:

First, ditch the shorts/pants it'll be much more comfortable to squat.

Second, the ground doesn't splash as much as a bowl full of water, so the problem probably isn't as bad as you might think.

Third, if your cathole is located on a slight slope you'll probably be able to get quite close too it, helping contain problems. A nice benefit of this - less strain on the ankles.

Fourth - you can pile up the dirt from the hole near your feet, as extra protection.

Fifth -by the time you hike out, whatever's on your boots will be long gone.

And final bonus comment - the backwoods is a place to enjoy, not to find out whether you can survive on questionable food choices. Eat food that you would eat in everyday life, cooked properly, and enjoy your trip!

Comment: Not in disagreement with your answer and tip to play it safe with food, but sometimes the backwoods encourages or even forces questionable food choices simply due to exposure to the elements :P bringing safer food helps with that however

Answer (score 3):

The following assumes you have enough time to follow all the steps, and assumes you are below timberline.

Find a log.

Dig your cathole on Side B of the log.

Plant your feet on Side A of the log.

Drop your nether garments to your knees.

Brace yourself with your hands on the log.

Sling your backside over the log.

Proceed.